# How to configure uninstaller's welcome page, INSTFILES page and unistaller finish page in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I want to change the default text present on the uninstaller's welcome page like the welcome page title should be "Welcome to my uninstall setup" and I want text below title like "Setup will guide you through the uninstallation of MYAPP. Before starting the uninstallation, make sure MYAPP is not running."
   On MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES page, I want Title as "Unistall MYAPP" below that i want to show "Remove MYAPP from your computer". On finish page I want to show "MYAPP has been uninstalled from your computer.Click 'Finish' to close the setup!"
I am doing it like below-

```
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
```

But it is showing me default text like "Name has been uninstalled from your computer" I want to configure this to show my own text on pages. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you even try to read the MUI documentation?

Answer (score 3):

You can override all the strings, you just have to lookup the defines in the [MUI documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html).

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE "Blah blah title"
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "Blah blah welcome page text"
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Header blah"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Subheader blah"
!define MUI_UNCONFIRMPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Blah blah title"
!define MUI_UNCONFIRMPAGE_TEXT_LOCATION "Blah blah location"
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Uninstall MYAPP"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Remove MYAPP from your computer"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT "Done blah"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT "blah blah"
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TITLE "Blah blah title"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT "MYAPP has been uninstalled from your computer.Click 'Finish' to close the setup!"
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Section 
SetOutPath "$Temp\MUITest"
WriteUninstaller "$Temp\MUITest\Uninst.exe"
ExecShell "" "$Temp\MUITest\Uninst.exe"
Quit
SectionEnd
Section Uninstall
SetAutoClose false ; Without this you never get to see MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT
Sleep 3333
Delete "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
RMDir "$InstDir"
SectionEnd
```